# How to run php code in smarty template file?

Tags: wordpress, smarty

I want to load wordpress in a smarty template. I used the code below to load wordpress in a php file and it worked. But it is not working a smarty template.

In php file:

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-load.php';
get_header();
?>
```

In smarty template file:

```
{php}
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-load.php';
get_header();
{/php}
```

Comment: it doesn't show anything just a blank page. no errors.

Comment: Can't you `$smarty->assign('wp_header', get_header())` in the PHP file and use `{$wp_header}` in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Smarty3? Have a look **[here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl)**.

`{php}` tag is deprecated, and from version 3.1 it's only available using `SmartyBC` class instead of `Smarty` class. They are just the same, but if you instance a `new SmartyBC()` object you will have a backward-compatible Smarty object supporting `{php}` tags.

Comment: i test php tags and it is working using this code {php}echo 'php is working';{/php}

Comment: @alhoseany Maybe the problem it's with the included file. Try to move that `echo 'php is working';` in a *somefile.php*, and try `{php}include 'somefile.php';{/php}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
             if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) 
             {
                echo '<ul class="err">';
                foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) 
                {
                    echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
                    }
                echo '</ul>';
                unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue